# Error compiling freetype make: Nothing to be done for 'unix'

Tags: linux, compilation, makefile, configure, freetype

I am trying to compile freetype 4.5.5 on ubuntu I am running ./configure and get the error make: Nothing to be done for 'unix' which almost sounds like a non error.

can anyone explain what this means and how I can get past the message the full output from ./configure is here http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/10642342/

I have GNU Make 4.0 for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu installed and running the latest stable ubuntu.

Comment: I don't see in the output where you typed `make` again, as the message suggested.

Comment: thats part of ./configure output which is displayed at the end i have not ran make myself manually, perhaps part of ./configure runs make for some reason.

Comment: The configure script shows a message near the beginning which tells you to run make again.  Then it runs another configure script, for an add-on.  I would try running make again...

Comment: I think you are right i just ignore that message and all seems to be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current version of freetype is *2.5.5* (see its [downloads](http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/freetype/) directory).  If you do

```
./configure
make
```

that should work.  The message about "Nothing to be done for 'unix'" is harmless.